# MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column '' cannot be null

Tags: mysql, case, mybatis, case-when

```
mapper:
<update id="updateSurplusAmountByPrimaryKeyAndMaterialTypeId" 
  parameterType="java.util.List">
    update db_logistics.table_inventory_material
    set surplusAmount=
    <foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index"
             separator=" " open="case" close="end">
        when inventoryId=#{item.inventoryId} and materialTypeId=# 
    {item.materialTypeId} then #{item.surplusAmount,jdbcType=INTEGER}
    </foreach>
    where inventoryId in
    <foreach collection="list" index="index" item="item"
             separator="," open="(" close=")">
        #{item.inventoryId,jdbcType=BIGINT}
    </foreach>
</update>
 fun updateSurplusAmountByPrimaryKeyAndMaterialTypeId(records: 
List<InventoryMaterial>): Int
data class InventoryMaterial(
    var inventoryId: Int = 0,
    var materialTypeId: Int = 0,
    var surplusAmount: Int = 0,
    var consumeSpeed: Float = 0f,
    var consumeAlarmDayCount: Int = 0,
    var updateDataTime: LocalDateTime =  LocalDateTime.now())
```

the error

"Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'surplusAmount' cannot be null"

when i modify the `when inventoryId=#{item.inventoryId} and materialTypeId=#{item.materialTypeId}`  to `when inventoryId=#{item.inventoryId}` , then the error gone.
But I need the to tow paramter inventoryId and materialTypeId can decide the inventoryId. So someone can give me some answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query that is executed selects records from `table_inventory_material` by `inventoryId` and updates them using the specified data for each `materialTypeId`.

The problem happens because for some `inventoryId` that you pass in the list the database has more `materialTypeId`s than you provided in the list that is passed as a parameter.

So the generated case statement yields `NULL` for the missing `materialTypeId` and the attempt to set `surplusAmount` to `NULL` cause the error.

Comment: var inverntoryMaterial = InventoryMaterial()
        inverntoryMaterial.inventoryId = 1
        inverntoryMaterial.materialTypeId = 20
        inverntoryMaterial.surplusAmount = 20
        inventoryMaterialMapper.updateSurplusAmountByPrimaryKeyAndMaterialTypeId(listOf(inverntoryMaterial)) I set the value, also have problem.

Comment: I haven't said you hadn't. I only say that you need to create `InventoryMaterial` for every `materialType` you have in DB for given `invertoryId`. How many records with `inventoryId==1` you have in db? That many items (all with different `materialTypeId`) should be passed to the query in the list.

Comment: I just modify like this  "where inventoryId in
        <foreach collection="list" index="index" item="item"
                 separator="," open="(" close=")">
            #{item.inventoryId,jdbcType=BIGINT}
        </foreach>
        and materialTypeId in
        <foreach collection="list" index="index" item="item"
                 separator="," open="(" close=")">
            #{item.materialTypeId,jdbcType=BIGINT}
        </foreach>
    </update>"